# Obtener elementos de clase para insert

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de hacer un insert a una tabla en la base de datos...pero como hago un llamado de elementos con un `for` desde otra clase, para lograr el `insert` de la información a las tablas?

```
public string Insert(string name, string hobbie)
{           
    string sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name,hobbie) VALUES (:NAME , :HOBBIE)";
    using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try{                   
            conexion.Open();
            using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion))
            {

            //COMO HAGO EL LLAMADO DE ELEMENTOS
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    comando.Parameters.Clear();
                    comando.Parameters.Add(":NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    comando.Parameters.Add(":HOBBIE", OracleDbType.Varchar2);                            
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }                      
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo. Como haces el llamado de que? si ya tenes los parametros que queres insertar y son los que vienen en la funcion...

Comment: En otra clase hay un arreglo con los datos

Comment: Ok.. pero en esta funcion no se ve ni la otra clase ni nada.. o sea, que tiene que ver esta funcion con tu problema?

Comment: Llegado el caso, esta funcion deberia recibir el objeto que queres recorrer, y ahi lo recorres...

Comment: tal vez, lo exprese mal, y si es recibir el objeto y recorrer, algun ejemplo, para guiarme?

Comment: para guiarte en que cosa? como enviar un objeto a una funcion? para recorrerlo depende el tipo de objeto, un for o un for each.. creo que te estas haciendo lio con algo simple...

Comment: obtener elementos del arreglo que esta en otra clase, recorrer con un for y asignalos a sus respectivos campos para lograr el insert

Comment: Vas a tener que mostrar el objeto que queres recorrer y como haces la llamada. Y esta funcion va a tener que cambiar.

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas iterar una lista de elementos lo primero que recomiendo es que definas una clase para agrupar los datos, como ser

```
public class Empleado
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string hobbie {get;set;}
}
```

entonces el insert quedaria

```
public string Insert(List<Empleado> empleados)
{           
    using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {             
        conexion.Open();

        string sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name,hobbie) VALUES (:NAME , :HOBBIE)";
        using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion))
        {
            foreach (var empleado in empleados)
            {
                comando.Parameters.Clear();

                var name = comando.Parameters.Add(":NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                name.Value = empleado.name;

                var hobbie = comando.Parameters.Add(":HOBBIE", OracleDbType.Varchar2);   
                hobbie.Value = empleado.hobbie;

                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }                      
        }
    }
}
```

Veras que el parametro se defini como `List<Empleado>` el cual iteras los datos  en el `foreach`